# Node.js hide html name on url

Tags: node.js

I have Node.js application can I hide the html file name from browser url to protect all html files

means if Node.js using port 9090 then the url browser will be `http://<ip address>:9090/`

and no html file names appears on browser url to protect these pages

Comment: What do you mean by protect the pages?

Comment: They don't need to see the html page in the URL... you can route URLs to any file you want. The two are not necessarily connected.

Comment: I means to avoid user access to html pages directly without going through index.html that call these pages

Comment: May be you're looking for sessions..

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it seems not working at all with node even if change the files extensions from html to php not working all

Comment: Yes I tried by using php but it seems Node.js not accept any php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Express.js](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) then you can use this method to render your HTML pages from a folder which has your static content.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('yourHTMLPage');
});
```

But a more suitable approach would be to to use cookies. First check if the request comes with your cookies, if Yes then redirect the request to your desired html page. If Not then render the index.html page and after that set cookies. **Express.js** provides all of these.